# How to access to element from another class

Tags: java, servlets

I have servlet where i need to show list of products first image next title and price.

i try with

```
    Proizvodi pr = new Proizvodi();
 for(int i=0; i<pr.getKatalog().size();i++)
            {
              out.println("<br />");
              out.print("<img src='pr.getKatalog().get(i).getImg()'>");
              out.print("<p>pr.getKatalog().get(i).getTitle()</p> ");
              out.print("<p>pr.getKatalog().get(i).getPrice()</p> ");
            }
```

but it doesn't work. I hope that u can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace this:

```
          out.print("<img src='pr.getKatalog().get(i).getImg()'>");
```

with

```
          out.print("<img src='" + pr.getKatalog().get(i).getImg() + "'>");
```

to get the method return value appended to the string. Otherwise `pr.getKatalog().get(i).getImg()` being in double quotes will be treated as a normal string and not as a method call.

You need to do the same thing for these statements as well:

```
   out.print("<p>pr.getKatalog().get(i).getTitle()</p> ");
   out.print("<p>pr.getKatalog().get(i).getPrice()</p> ");
```

Comment: Tnx a lot. I have one question more i need the pic, title and price to be in one line but there are in new line and why it does'n show the pic?

Comment: @If you want all the information in the same line then don't use multiple out.print, simply put everthing in the same out.print.

Comment: Ok i accept it. I'm new here i didn't know that i need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the newline issue you mentioned, remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags from all of the out.print() statements and it should be in all one line then.